# VS2010 Database Project Deployment: Database objects build order

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, deployment, project

Im kinda new to VS2010 Database Project Deployment. So before, using this one, I usually create a deployment script using vbscript where all the database scripts are complied into one file. Using vbscript i can specify which data objects will come first. Normally, i run table scripts first, then user-defined function scripts, stored procedures, so on..

I want to know how I can control which data objects are to be executed first. Whats happening now when deploying the database project, the stored procedures are executed first before the user-defined functions. Those stored procedures are dependent on the user-defined functions.

Thanks!
Rinn

Comment: it's not clear what your question is.  Are you encountering a specific error message?  Are you describing behaviour similar to this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623264/dependency-issues-not-handled-correctly-in-database-projects ?